# Is this a reasonably written test for a college 100-level software class midterm?

Tags: c++

I am a student working on an undergrad computer science degree and I'm having a nightmare of a time in this class. The class is the first programming class for CS majors at my school. It is incredibly poorly taught and I'm debating going to the Department head and filing a grievance.

Here is a test question from our midterm that accounted for 25% of the grade. Is this a reasonably written coherent programming question? Can anyone here make heads or tails out of this? I feel like it is poorly worded and very confusing and that a professor needs to be MUCH clearer and put more effort into writing a test. Here's the question:

**(25%) Suppose input data about [simplified] New York street lights has the following fields in order: avenue, street, timeR, timeG, timeY. All the fields are integers, and the time fields indicate the number of seconds the light stays each color. Write a code fragment that reads the data from keyboard input (no prompting needed), and outputs the 2 largest green light delays on avenue a. You may assume:**

The avenua a has been initialized to some legal avenue
There are no errors in input (though the input will contain data for all avenues)
The times are distinct (i.e., no two times are the same)
The cin returns false when there is no more data

Am I out of line for being annoyed about this? Or is it a reasonable complaint? I got 209 out of a potential 400 points on this test and it curved to about a B+. However, I am still incredibly frustrated with the poor quality of this class. I am an adult student and eager to learn and get a software job and I feel like my time is being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow isn't an academia discussion site.

Comment: Was there any more elaboration on the input data? It's incredibly broad

Comment: None whatsoever. That is the entire question. Previous questions on the test didn't tie into this question either. It's a stand alone question.

Comment: For 25% value of the grade I would expect a lot more clarity

Comment: Interesting question if I were to do it outside of academic purposes. A nightmare to have on a test, though, I wholeheartedly agree with you. Could you share the code you submitted for the test?

Comment: @AndrewLi I don't see how any academia discussion site could possibly handle this unless an IT guy happened by. We've had plenty of questions of this general type before.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this a reasonably written coherent programming question?

No.

> Can anyone here make heads or tails out of this?

Yes but only by making assumptions.

> I feel like it is poorly worded and very confusing and that a professor needs to be MUCH clearer and put more effort into writing a test.

I agree.

> Here's the question:
>
> (25%) Suppose input data about [simplified] New York street lights has the following fields in order: avenue, street, timeR, timeG, timeY.

Separated by what? How are the fields separated? How are the records separated?

> All the fields are integers, and the time fields indicate the number of seconds the light stays each color. Write a code fragment that reads the data from keyboard input (no prompting needed), and outputs the 2 largest green light delays on avenue a. You may assume:
>
> - The avenua a has been initialized to some legal avenue

I don't know what this means.

> - There are no errors in input (though the input will contain data for all avenues)
> - The times are distinct (i.e., no two times are the same)

I don't see why that matters.

> - The cin returns false when there is no more data

You don't have to assume that. It's stated in the C++ language specification. But `cin` gives the hint.

*Assuming* the input is text, *assuming* the records are lines, and *assuming* the fields are separated by spaces, you can do the input part of the exercise entirely via `cin` and the `>>` operator, surrounded by a `while (cin)` loop.

But unless that's what the exercise is *entirely* about, in some stated context, it is not adequately specified, and if given that in a professional environment I would be sending it back for clarification. There are too many possibilities:

- space-separated text fields on lines
- comma-separated text fields on lines
- fixed-width binary fields in fixed-width records
- ...

Comment: I assume the input is space-separated since I wouldn't expect students in an introductory class would know how to handle anything else.  At my school, many students made it to second and third year courses without learning how to "return a value" without printing it to `cout`.

Comment: @MaxLybbert Strange curriculum. I got past that in Computer Programmning 101, first term. In my second year we were expected to program teletype input on a micro in assembler.